# A simple python project with sum and average

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use python 3 and I have to make a program that creates all the multiples of 5 to 100,then print them as well as their average.I have tried this but...

```
for i in range(0, 101):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        x = 0
        x += 1
        y = sum(i)
        z = y/x 
        print(i)
        print(z)
```

When I try this i get :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chriskaf/Desktop/(3)count.py", line 5, in <module>
    y = sum(i)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Thanks for you time :)

Comment: Inside the loop, `i` will be a single integer. You can't `sum` an integer (it is not iterable).

Comment: What exact behaviour of function `sum` were you expecting?

Comment: you have to pass an iterable type as parameter. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
counter = 0

sum_numbers = 0

for number in range(1,101):

    if number % 5 ==0:

        counter += 1

        sum_numbers += number

        avg = sum_numbers / float(counter)

        print (number, avg)
```

Output:

```
(5, 5.0)
(10, 7.5)
(15, 10.0)
(20, 12.5)
(25, 15.0)
(30, 17.5)
(35, 20.0)
(40, 22.5)
(45, 25.0)
(50, 27.5)
(55, 30.0)
(60, 32.5)
(65, 35.0)
(70, 37.5)
(75, 40.0)
(80, 42.5)
(85, 45.0)
(90, 47.5)
(95, 50.0)
(100, 52.5)
```

Your code had a couple of issues.

- the `x` counter was reset on every iteration (it was always set to 0, and after that to 1)
- missuse of `sum` (error code here) - you cant `sum` a single digit (which is what `i` is) - the sum function description is: ***sum(sequence[, start]) -> value
  Return the sum of a sequence of numbers (NOT strings) plus the value
  of parameter 'start' (which defaults to 0).  When the sequence is
  empty, return start.***
- you are dividing `y` by an `int` (would result in nearest round int, I believe you want float results)

Hope that helps!

Comment: IIRC Python 3 automatically does float division, unlike Python 2 where at least one value has to be a float.

Comment: Ty wasnt aware. I use mostly 2.7 due to libraries compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to create a list where you save all values. Then apply the `sum` and `average`:

```
total = []
for i in range(0, 101):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        total.append(i)

total_sum = sum(total)
total_average = sum(total)/len(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better, use the "step" parameter of **range** to get exactly the numbers you want.  Also, don't re-compute the sum.

```
total = [i for i in range(5, 101, 5)]
total_sum = sum(total)
total average = total_sum / len(total)
```